# Could not load accumulo constraint, getting UnsatisfiableConstraint failure

Tags: java, accumulo

I have been trying to work on custom constraint in Accumulo. I have created the constraint by implementing org.apache.accumulo.core.constraints.Constraint .

But when applying it to the table I am getting following error

> Constraint Failures: ConstraintViolationSummary(constrainClass:org.apache.accumulo.tserver.constraints.UnsatisfiableConstraint,violationCode:-1,violationDescription:Failed to load constraints, not accepting mutations., numberOfViolatingMutations:1)

below is my code snippet

```
 package samplepackageforconstraints;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collection;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.apache.accumulo.core.constraints.Constraint;
    import org.apache.accumulo.core.data.ColumnUpdate;
    import org.apache.accumulo.core.data.Mutation;

public class LengthConstraintsTest implements Constraint{

    private static final short NOT_ENOUGH_LENGTH = 1;

    @Override
    public List<Short> check(Environment env, Mutation mutation) {
        List<Short> violations = null;
        Collection<ColumnUpdate> updates = mutation.getUpdates();

        for (ColumnUpdate columnUpdate : updates) {

            if (!isLessThanThree(columnUpdate.getValue()))
                violations = addViolation(violations, NOT_ENOUGH_LENGTH);

        }
        return violations;
    }

    @Override
    public String getViolationDescription(short violationCode) {
         switch (violationCode) {
          case NOT_ENOUGH_LENGTH:
            return "Value should be more than 3 character";
        }
        return null;
    }

    private List<Short> addViolation(List<Short> violations, short violation) {
        if (violations == null) {

            violations = new ArrayList<Short>();
            violations.add(violation);
        } else if (!violations.contains(violation)) {

            violations.add(violation);
        }
        return violations;
    }

    private boolean isLessThanThree(byte[] value) {
        if(value.length <3)
        return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
}
```

I have followed the steps given in the  [user manual of accumulo version 1.7](https://accumulo.apache.org/1.7/accumulo_user_manual.html)
also [cloudera](http://archive.cloudera.com/accumulo-c5/cdh/5/accumulo/constraints.html)  for loading the constraint

I am using  version: 1.6.0-cdh5.1.4 of accumulo

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the constraint cannot be loaded, this means there's a problem loading the class from the classpath (usually), or (less likely) the class doesn't correspond to the `Constraint` interface.

You need to add the jar containing your custom constraint to the classpath of every tablet server.

You can further debug this by checking the tserver logs on the node which threw this exception.

Comment: Thanks Christopher :) Is there any way to log the mutation that failed a constraints ?

Comment: @Supriti That's not currently logged right now, because there's no sensible way to identify a mutation other than by its contents... which could be large, not unique, pollute the server logs with user data, and in general, is not very unhelpful. The best way to identify the mutation which caused the problem is in the client, by retrying all mutations, one at a time, since the last successful flush. The error above was a general error about loading constraints and would have happened with any/every mutation sent.

Comment: In theory, your mutation could log more specific details about the problems in the mutations it is checking, before it returns from its `check` method, but it's not required in the interface, and it'd be entirely a per-Constraint behavior.

Comment: ok . I will keep this in mind and try to implement some logic in client side. Thanks again. It's lot of help